# Django queryset with partial nested lists

Tags: django

I have two models :

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    client = models.ForeignKey(client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Client(model.Model):
    name = models.CharFiled(max_length=255)
```

Assume my data is :

```
Client table - [{id:1,name:client1}, {id:2, name:client2}
Project table - [{id:1, name: project1, client:1},
                 {id:2, name: project2, client:1},
                 {id:3, name: project3, client:2}]
```

a Client.objects.all() QuerySet will return two objects, client1 and client2 which client 1 has 2 projects and client2 have only 1.

I am trying to order a QuerySet by a project name, but per Client object. doing so this way :

```
clients = Client.objects.order_by("project__name")
```

as Expected the result will provide 3 clients object, 2 for client1 and one for client 2. this is the output :

```
[{id:1, name:client1, projects : [{id:1, name: project1},{id:2, name: project2}]},
[id:1, name:client1, projects : [{id:1, name: project1},{id:2, name: project2}]},
[id:2, name:client1, projects : [{id:3, name: project3}]}]
```

However, my problem is that each client object contains all the projects and not only the specific ordered one.

I am trying to filter for each client object, even if the client is the same only the requested ordered projects.

I can theoretically do that manually after receiving the queryset, but I assume there is a way to do it because the request does know which project specifically causes the creation of a new row in the queryset.

my expected output for the given data is a query set with the following data (which I send to a serializer btw) notice that I have two client object but with different projects list because of the order_by break it down. this is what I want to achieve :

```
[{id:1, name:client1, projects : [{id:1, name: project1}]},
{id:1, name:client1, projects : [{id:2, name: project2}]},
{id:2, name:client1, projects : [{id:3, name: project3}]}]
```

Comment: Use `related name` in foreign key and then use `prefetch related` then use order by.

Comment: @shantanu I am not sure how this can help me?

Comment: Can you share what is your expected output?

Comment: @shantanu I added the expected output to the question. thank !

Answer (score 0):

You should query in the opposite way: fetch the `Project`s ordered by name, with a `.select_related(..)` on the `client`:

```
projects = Project.objects.select_related('client').order_by('name')
```

Then for each `Project` you can fetch the client with `.client`. This is more efficient, but also more sensical, since you are essentially processing a list of projects, with a client attached to it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I simplified my structure to show the problem I am facing and going this route won't help my more sophisticated issue. I have to make the query from the client to project.